# Moving webservice from http to https

Tags: wcf, web-services, soap, dotnetopenauth

Recently, I've been working on a WCF SOAP webservice which is protected by OAuth via the DotNetOpenAuth webservice, hosted on IIS7. I'm happy to say that I've got the project to work- that is, it works on http.

The next step is to move the two projects (consumer and service provider, the latter containing the webservice) to https. However this is causing a bit of trouble.

When making the call to the DataApi.svc from the consumer, I receive the following error;

```
Server Error in '/consumerexample/v2' Application.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

The username is not provided. Specify username in ClientCredentials. 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request.     Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: The username is not provided. Specify username in ClientCredentials.

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.  

Stack Trace: 


[InvalidOperationException: The username is not provided. Specify username in ClientCredentials.]
System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg) +4727747
System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type) +1725
OAuthConsumer.SampleServiceProvider.IDataApi.retrieveTimeTable(String weekVan, String weekTot) +0
OAuthConsumer.SampleServiceProvider.DataApiClient.retrieveTimeTable(String weekVan, String weekTot) in C:\Program Files\TimeTableWebService\consumer\OAuthConsumer\Service References\SampleServiceProvider\Reference.cs:108
OAuthConsumer.<>c__DisplayClass6.<retrieveTimeTable_Click>b__5(DataApiClient client) in C:\Program Files\TimeTableWebService\consumer\OAuthConsumer\GetTimeTable.aspx.cs:76
OAuthConsumer.GetTimeTable.CallService(Func`2 predicate) in C:\Program Files\TimeTableWebService\consumer\OAuthConsumer\GetTimeTable.aspx.cs:129
OAuthConsumer.GetTimeTable.retrieveTimeTable_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Program Files\TimeTableWebService\consumer\OAuthConsumer\GetTimeTable.aspx.cs:76
System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +154
System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +3707

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.237
```

On http, this works like a charm. When I debug the consumer locally, the whole OAuth authorization works beautifully. It is only when the method retrieveTimeTable in my DataApi.svc is called that I receive this error.

On IIS7 I've enabled both Anonymous and Basic Authentication for both the consumer and the service provider sites. The web.config files are as follows;

**Consumer**

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <bindings>
    <wsHttpBinding>
      <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IDataApi" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
     openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
     bypassProxyOnLocal="false" transactionFlow="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
     maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="999999999" messageEncoding="Text"
     textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true" allowCookies="false">

        <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
       maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
        <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00"
       enabled="false" />

        <security mode="Transport">  
    <transport clientCredentialType="Basic" proxyCredentialType="None" realm=""/>  
    <message clientCredentialType="Certificate" algorithmSuite="Default" /> 
        </security>          

      </binding>
    </wsHttpBinding>
  </bindings>

  <client>
    <endpoint address="https://websrv.hszuyd.nl/serviceprovider/v2/DataApi.svc" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IDataApi" contract="SampleServiceProvider.IDataApi" name="WSHttpBinding_IDataApi">
      <identity>
        <dns value="localhost" />
      </identity>
    </endpoint>        
  </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

**Service provider**

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <behaviors>
    <endpointBehaviors>
      <behavior name="DataApiBehavior">
        <webHttp />
      </behavior>
      <behavior name="wsHttpEnablingBehaviour">
        <webHttp/>
      </behavior>
    </endpointBehaviors>            

    <serviceBehaviors>  
      <behavior name="DataApiBehavior">
        <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true" />
        <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        <serviceAuthorization serviceAuthorizationManagerType="OAuthServiceProvider.Code.OAuthAuthorizationManager, OAuthServiceProvider" principalPermissionMode="Custom" />
      </behavior>
      <behavior name="wsHttpEnablingBehaviour">
        <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
        <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
      </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
  <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />

  <bindings>
    <wsHttpBinding>   
      <binding name="wsHttpBinding" maxReceivedMessageSize="999999999">
        <security mode="Transport">
          <transport clientCredentialType="Basic" />    
        </security>
      </binding>               
    </wsHttpBinding>
  </bindings>
  <services>
    <service behaviorConfiguration="DataApiBehavior" name="OAuthServiceProvider.DataApi">
      <clear/>
      <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="OAuthServiceProvider.Code.IDataApi" name="Oauth" bindingConfiguration="wsHttpBinding" />               
    </service>
  </services>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Probably your consumer side uses some proxy to call the provider but does not specify user/pass which are required for the basic authentication.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! I should have pointed out, though, both the consumer and service provider are on the same server. In fact, they're two seperate applications within the same IIS7 Site, which I believe would mean that there is no proxy. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: I wan not talking on http proxy but on a wcf proxy. somewhere in the consumer you have something like p = new ProviderService(); p.Call(). You need to specify authentication details in p.ClientCredentials.UserName.User and Password

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry but I don't get it. The client should not use basic authentication. Basic authentication should only be used for the Authorize.aspx page. So I think the problem is that the webservice itself uses basic authentication instead of oauth, but I don't now how to solve this. If i remove the binding="wsHttpBinding" of the endpoint is doesn't work. (I'm a colleague of Nico)